# What specs do Skylander RFID use?

Tags: skylanders

I have seen a lot of info about the Skylanders using the RFID chips. I even know that a person created a driver/project to use the portal to download the data off of them.

My question is whether their are any other means to read the RFID data off a figure? I have heard that android phones have apps to interface with RFID, but I didn't know what the Skylander RFID specs were or if RFID reading tools are generic and can work with any type of RFID?

It just that I am interested in RFID technology and how a person can possibly use it in their own applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The portal RFID device operates at 13.56 MHz and uses standard RFID protocol.  Any RFID reader that can operate at this frequency **should** be able to work with the figurines, though I haven't tested this myself.  The FCC filing for the portal device may be found here:

https://fjallfoss.fcc.gov/oetcf/eas/reports/ViewExhibitReport.cfm?mode=Exhibits&RequestTimeout=500&calledFromFrame=N&application_id=170335&fcc_id=%27XLU83973790%27

By the way, if you are interested in RFID technology the portal may not be a bad way to get started. Make has a really cool article about how they put together the first prototype for the game using Arduino and hacking together a bunch of off the shelf technology pieces (including a kitchen drain!) to get a proof of concept they could demo.  ([Developing Skylanders’ Innovative “Portal of Power”](http://blog.makezine.com/2012/03/13/alt-gdc-developing-skylanders-innovative-portal-of-power/))